# How can I set the default value of a DateTime field in a SharePoint list to also contain the current time?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a DateTime field in my SharePoint 2013 list. I have specified the default value for the field to be =Today. The problem is this only specifies the date part of the field. The time part is left as 00:00. How can I get the time information in there as well.

I want to present the user with the current time as default, which will be used most of the time. However, it should be possible for the user to be able to specify a different time if required.

Comment: Do you want to set it programmatically or in the settings of the list?

Comment: I just need to set it once in the settings of the list. I do not need to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=Today() gives only the current date, =Now() gives the current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

yourDefaultDate = DateTime.Now();

instead of DateTime.Today();